# generic method to add int, float, in c#

Tags: c#, generics

**I am writing a generic method for addition of integers, float, double**

```
public T  Swap<T>( T value1,  T value2)
{
    T temp;
    temp = value1 +value2;
    return temp;
}
```

I am getting an error:

**Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'**

I am using VS 2005, can anyone tell me how to achive it?

Comment: It can't be done. There's no way to constrain a generic type to be numeric, which would (hand-wave) be what is necessary to have this work.

Comment: Didn't Mono do something like interfaces for basic arithmetic, with compiler support for the basic types? I wonder how long it'll take for Microsoft to realize it would be a nice addition in their release as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this directly. Generics in .NET just don't support it. However, there are other options available:

- In C# 4, you can use dynamic typing:

  ```
  public static T Sum<T>(T value1,  T value2)
  {
      dynamic temp = value1;
      temp += value2;
      return temp;
  }
  ```

  EDIT: I hadn't noticed that you were using VS2005. Do you really *have* to? Any chance you could upgrade to something a little more recent?
- Marc Gravell wrote code in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) to do this pretty efficiently with delegates. See the [usage page](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) for more information. The implementation in MiscUtil uses C# 3 and .NET 3.5, but I believe Marc has a *separate* implementation of the same ideas in .NET 2 using `DynamicMethod`. We can ping him to check if you need that...

Comment: I didn't think you could do C# 4 in VS2005.